# Property 'push' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339) with bracket properties access

Tags: typescript, next.js

We are using Next + Typescript (+ stuff) to create some graphs.

We have an object with n-properties and and a string["prop1", "prop2", ...] with a subset of those properties.
I used the approach

```
function isObjKey <T>(
  prop: string,
  obj: MyObj
): prop is keyof Omit<T, number | symbol> {
  return prop in MyObj;
}
```

to be able to use myObj[prop] and it works.

I have to collect the data from many myObj(s) (caluclating mean value) and than store the value in another object:

```
export interface Data {
  prop1: number[];
  prop2: number[];
  prop3: number[];
  ...
};
```

so at the end i am using similar approach as MyObj:

```
function isOtherObjKey <T>(
  prop: string,
  obj: MyOtherObj
): prop is keyof Omit<T, number | symbol> {
  return prop in MyOtherObj;
}
```

and

```
if (prop && isOtherObjKey (prop, myOtherObj)) {
 resultsData[prop].push(parseFloat(totalResult.toFixed(2)));
}
```

but i get the error
Property 'push' does not exist on type 'never'.ts(2339)

EDIT: we switched to a combo number[] + 2dArr: [][] and it works.
Case closed.

This is the code:

```
export function calculateMeanValues(country_arr: string[], filteredSurvey: AutoSurvey[]) {
  let resultsData: Data = {
    rent: [],
    utilities: [],
    food: [],
    basicItems: [],
    transportation: [],
    educationTotal: []
  };

  const fiveVar: string[] = ["rent", "utilities", "food", "basicItems", "transportation", "educationTotal"];

  for (let fiveVarIndex= 0; fiveVarIndex < fiveVar.length; fiveVarIndex++) {
    const prop = fiveVar[fiveVarIndex];

    for (let i = 0; i < country_arr.length; i++) {
      const lowerPart = filteredSurvey
      .filter((s) => { if (prop && isSurveyKey(prop, s)) { return s[prop] && country_arr[i] === s.country; }})
      .map((s) => { if (prop && isSurveyKey(prop, s)) { return s[prop]; }})
      .length;

      const totalResult = filteredSurvey
      .filter((s) => { if (prop && isSurveyKey(prop, s)) { return s[prop] && country_arr[i] === s.country; }})
      .map((s) => { if (prop && isSurveyKey(prop, s)) { return s[prop]; } else {return 0}})
      .reduce(function add(sum, rent) { return sum + rent; }, 0) / lowerPart;
      
      if (prop && isDataKey(prop, resultsData)) {
        console.log("typeof prop: ", typeof prop);
        console.log("prop: ", prop);
        resultsData[prop].push(parseFloat(totalResult.toFixed(2)));
      }
    } 
  }
  return resultsData;
}
```